# Need advice on Rails app site planning: Get JSON from other site and pass it for JS Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller

I am new in web app development. Recently I've create an app:
http://konganize.herokuapp.com

The badges (the icons in body) are collected from another site via `jQuery.ajax()`.

For mash-up, searching/sorting & user login, I'm going to collect data in server side (Rails).

My plan is like-this: [Google Document](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1roDeiHrMDiw8Z9WWsg1GBdjsE60eEAbYcFOxZmp2jpw/edit)

Is it a good approach to collect JSON/XML/API data? Or say, should I use a separate Controller to do it? (Or use rake-task/helper/etc?)

Many thanks for advice and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do whatever makes the most sense in your case.

1. If being realtime has more priority value for you - then I would suggest talk to the API directly.
2. If being realtime has a moderate value for you - Then you should look into doing a rake task to fetch the data and storing it locally and then doing a mash-up. You can schedule this rake task to run at a set frequency of your preferred choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm more confident to start now :) I think I'll need them both for different target.

Comment: For case 1, should I do all things in Controller? I can get the json file into string. But don't know how to use jQuery's ajax() to get the data. I guess I'm fail to write properly in route.rb